# Adding element to list in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out how to add element to pandas column for single row.

```
index = ['a','b','c','d']
df = pd.DataFrame(index = index)
df['Col'] = [[]] * len(index)

df.loc['d','Col'].append('AA')
```

returns:

```
    Col
a   [AA]
b   [AA]
c   [AA]
d   [AA]
```

I look for value 'AA' to be in the last row only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should create the list of empty list by , avoid same object assignment. Also you can use `.loc` for assign the value in pandas

```
df['Col'] = [[] for x in df.index]
df.loc['d','Col']='AA'
df
  Col
a  []
b  []
c  []
d  AA

df.loc['d','Col'].append('AA')
df
    Col
a    []
b    []
c    []
d  [AA]
```

Comment: Thank you. I will read the explanation in linked post.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df.loc['d','Col'] = 'AA'
```

This should work for you

Edit:

Based on your edit, maybe this could be more efficient:

```
df.iloc[-1] = [['AA']]
```

Comment: you are not adding a value to the list...

Comment: I'm sorry, but the title of the question is confused and seems to be different of what Ranny is asking. I believe that Ranny is trying to insert a value in a specific position of the data frame. Is that correct?

Comment: yea, maybe ­­­­

Comment: it works, but I iterate and add elements to list in each row one by one. This method will do but it seems to me a long way around some simpler solution.

Comment: check my edit and let me know if it works for you